# Xamarin.Forms Toolbar Animation with Android Design Support Library

Tags: xamarin.forms, androiddesignsupport

i want realize a page like the one below, using xamarin.forms mixing up some renderers.

[image]

This is a pure Android example, and it works fine http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/
but how to achieve it with .forms?

As shown in the example code, the page is composed by a

CoordinatorLayout

. AppBarLayout

.. CollapsingToolbarLayout

... ImageView (etc...)

. RecycleView --> It should be fine use the .forms listview here, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on forms project and not native I would go by inserting complete native page into xamarin forms project. You can find more info how to create a renderer for native page in forms: https://blog.xamarin.com/customize-your-xamarin-forms-app-with-pages-for-each-platform/